# Oracle PL/SQL asinging value to variale by dynamic funcion call

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, dblink

I have this working part of code, is a fragment of bigger working function. At current form it is operating at single instance "DBLINK", i need to modify it to dynamicly switch instance by substituting dblink.

```
  begin 
      pNDRZ := RW_DOK_SYSTEM.create_header@DBLINK(  aNMGZ => NULL, aNKNT =>     pNKNT    , aREZR =>  'T' , aNTPD =>     pNTPD,     aNODD =>     pNODD    , aOPHP =>     pOPER);
     B2B_P_LOG_ADD(pPAKC => 'B2B_P_DRZ_H_NEW', pERRO => SQLERRM, pTEXT => ' 2.1 Tworz naglowek - OK', pDAKT => SYSDATE, pDBLK => pDBLK, pNRZM => pNRZM, pNDRZ => pNDRZ, pPOZC => pPOZC, pNKNT => pNKNT, pNTWR => pNTWR, pILSP => pILSP, pCNSP => pCNSP, pCBSP => pCBSP, pNPRM => pNPRM, pUWAG => pUWAG, pSTAK => dbms_utility.format_call_stack );
       exception
        when others then
         B2B_P_LOG_ADD(pPAKC => 'B2B_P_DRZ_H_NEW', pERRO => SQLERRM||' - '||SQLStatement2, pTEXT => wynik||' 2.1 Tworz naglowek - ERROR', pDAKT => SYSDATE, pDBLK => pDBLK, pNRZM => pNRZM, pNDRZ => pNDRZ, pPOZC => pPOZC, pNKNT => pNKNT, pNTWR => pNTWR, pILSP => pILSP, pCNSP => pCNSP, pCBSP => pCBSP, pNPRM => pNPRM, pUWAG => pUWAG, pSTAK => dbms_utility.format_call_stack );
      return(0);
  end;
```

The key line is this one, rest is massive log and error handling:

```
 pNDRZ := RW_DOK_SYSTEM.create_header@DBLINK(  aNMGZ => NULL, aNKNT =>     pNKNT    , aREZR =>  'T' , aNTPD =>     pNTPD,     aNODD =>     pNODD    , aOPHP =>     pOPER);
```

pNDRZ is an uniqe id for document. I need to modify that code to dynamic form in witch i substitute the dblink at the function call.

How to dynamic call function, i can do that with procedure but i have stuck with this.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need dynamic SQL (as you presumed). To do so

- create a local variable which will be used to *compose* the SQL statement (`l_str` in my example)

  - why not using it directly? Because dynamic SQL is difficult to debug so first display it and - once it works well - execute it
- if code you posted is part of a stored procedure, you'll probably pass database link name as a parameter. I created a local variable to serve that purpose (`l_db_link`)

I've shortened those lengthy commands you wrote, no point in writing them all.

```
declare
  l_str      varchar2(200);   -- used to compose a dynamic SQL statement
  l_db_link  varchar2(30) := 'ORCL';
  pndrz      number;          -- just guessing; I don't know its datatype
begin
  l_str := 'select rw_dok_system.create_header@' || l_db_link || '(anmgz => null) from dual';
  execute immediate l_str into pndrz;
  
  b2b_p_log_add(ppakc => 'B2B_P_DRZ_H_NEW');

exception
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works, i get ora-14551 cannot perform a DML operation inside a query. This query ads one row to documents table. I can't use autonomous transaction -its to risky. I decided to use cascade of else-if statements. One for every possible department. And yes i know, that's hardcoding an "disaster in the making" :( But i have limited time. I will try to make it better some day in the distant future ;) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. As of error you got - well, I didn't know what procedure is doing (obviously, DML). I'm glad you *know* what's going on and how to fix it.